# Wix Setup: Windows service start retry count

Tags: .net, windows, service, wix, windows-installer

I wrote a small windows service which throws an Exception at startup.

Now when I try to install the service with a wix setup, I expect the setup to fail immediately, because the service fails to start and in case of an update, roll back the previous (working) version.

But actually, the setup is trying to start the service about 7 times including timeouts in between, which takes the whole process about 4 minutes until it gives up. After that, the rollback restores the working service.

Is there any way to reduce the number of retries or even disabling it?

Edit: WiX configuration as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <?define Simple.Service_TargetDir=$(var.Simple.Service.TargetDir)?>
  <?define UpgradeGuid = "{b9a26766-d805-4c70-a43a-032277ea5b42}"?>
  <?define Manufacturer = "ElStefan"?>
  <?define Version = "!(bind.FileVersion.Simple.Library.dll)"?>
  <Product Id="*" Name="Simple.Service" Language="1033" Version="$(var.Version)" Manufacturer="$(var.Manufacturer)" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeGuid)">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="temp.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

    <Upgrade Id="$(var.UpgradeGuid)">
      <UpgradeVersion Minimum="$(var.Version)" IncludeMinimum="no" OnlyDetect="yes" Property="NEWPRODUCTFOUND" />
      <UpgradeVersion Minimum="$(var.Version)" IncludeMinimum="yes" OnlyDetect="yes" Property="SAMEPRODUCTFOUND" />
      <UpgradeVersion Maximum="$(var.Version)" IncludeMaximum="yes" OnlyDetect="no" Property="OLDPRODUCTFOUND" />
    </Upgrade>

    <CustomAction Id="PreventDowngrading" Error="Newer version already installed." />

    <CustomAction Id="PreventReinstall" Error="This version is already installed." />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="PreventDowngrading" After="FindRelatedProducts">NEWPRODUCTFOUND</Custom>
      <Custom Action="PreventReinstall" After="FindRelatedProducts">SAMEPRODUCTFOUND</Custom>
      <RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallFinalize" />
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
    <InstallUISequence>
      <Custom Action="PreventDowngrading" After="FindRelatedProducts">NEWPRODUCTFOUND</Custom>
      <Custom Action="PreventReinstall" After="FindRelatedProducts">SAMEPRODUCTFOUND</Custom>
    </InstallUISequence>

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Simple.ServiceSetup">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
  </Product>
  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="Company" Name="$(var.Manufacturer)">
          <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Simple Service" />
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Id="Simple.Service.exe" Guid="acf92f33-8af9-47d2-9c9b-1044b3b8e0ba">
        <File Id="Simple.Service.exe" Name="Simple.Service.exe" Source="$(var.Simple.Service_TargetDir)Simple.Service.exe" />
        <ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstaller" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes" Name="Simple Service" DisplayName="Simple Service" Start="auto" ErrorControl="ignore" Interactive="no" />
        <ServiceControl Id="ServiceController" Name="Simple Service" Start="install" Stop="uninstall" Remove="uninstall" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="Simple.Library.dll" Guid="3b6edd98-a214-4fbb-8c67-756b3fbf55e8">
        <File Id="Simple.Library.dll" Name="Simple.Library.dll" Source="$(var.Simple.Service_TargetDir)Simple.Library.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="Simple.Library.pdb" Guid="edde4d5c-b175-489b-a0f1-7a01cb49ca34">
        <File Id="Simple.Library.pdb" Name="Simple.Library.pdb" Source="$(var.Simple.Service_TargetDir)Simple.Library.pdb" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="Simple.Library.xml" Guid="8228e4eb-b348-4a8a-9187-29a50e197692">
        <File Id="Simple.Library.xml" Name="Simple.Library.xml" Source="$(var.Simple.Service_TargetDir)Simple.Library.xml" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="Simple.Service.exe.config" Guid="739ab8cd-a445-428b-b2a7-e555c5c951c8" NeverOverwrite="yes" Permanent="yes">
        <File Id="Simple.Service.exe.config" Name="Simple.Service.exe.config" Source="$(var.Simple.Service_TargetDir)Simple.Service.exe.config" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="Simple.Service.pdb" Guid="8208eaca-6008-440c-ae96-3b9dfd4d81e6">
        <File Id="Simple.Service.pdb" Name="Simple.Service.pdb" Source="$(var.Simple.Service_TargetDir)Simple.Service.pdb" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Edit2: https://github.com/ElStefan/SimpleService contains the full code I'm using. I also released two setup versions there, version 1.0.0 will start and run, version 1.0.1 will crash on start.

Comment: You should show your WiX service install and control source. For example the default wait value of "yes" will cause Windows to wait for the service to initialize completely.

Comment: I tested it with wait="no", but then the setup just finishes without rollback and and the service would be broken.

Comment: I assume you see the 7 attempts in an MSI log, that could be useful to post, I've never heard of 7 attempts to start a service unless it's configured with failure actions to restart it. But the services startup protocol is a message sequence with a 30 second timeout, so it can take at least that while Windows waits for the service to respond. If the service is broken then you'll see the maximum timeouts as windows waits for it.

Comment: Made a logfile with settings "/L*v": https://pastebin.com/JaVvCZRQ - the retries are not visible in there, but I can see it in the task manager and in the event log.

Comment: The installer is just doing one start service, so something else is going on if you're seeing multiple attempts to start it. If the SCM is retrying then the service might be configured with error recovery, as I said before, and that is causing the SCM to retry multiple times. I don't think this is anything in Windows Installer.

Comment: You're talking about the recovery actions (first failure, second failure, subsequent failures), right? But the wix setup does not contain recovery action configurations. And I just checked on the installed service, there are definitely no actions configured. I get the same result on other systems (Win10Pro) which never had the service installed before. I agree that this may not be  the installers fault, but it has to be configurable somewhere.

Comment: I am getting this exact behavior, same number of retries.  I have custom actions that configure the services before they start.  If the custom action fails, the services try to start anyway and the retry process is taking way too long.